# bootstrap $('.multiselect').multiselect() CONFLICT

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page in which i am using handlebars to fill two form elements one after the other. Both forms have bootstrap multiselects.

I need to fire the

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect()
```

on rendering the second form but as bootstrap has already added

```
'.multiselect'
```

and when i try using

```
('.multiselect').multiselect()
```

the first form is messed up

One solution i see is use different class names for multi-selects but i am doubtful as it looks like a hack to me.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in inspecting the demo page ( http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ ) , each select hasn't class name, just id.

source : `<select id="example1" style="display: inline-block;">...</select>`

So you can use 'id' instead of generic classname to construct multiselect.